# When is this stochastic integral a martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $B = (B_t)_{t \in [0,T} $ a Brownian motion.
Let $H = (H_t)_{t \in [0,T}, G = (G_t)_{t \in [0,T} $ be progressively measurable.

What are the conditions on $H,G$ such that $(\int_0^t H_s G_s dB_s)_{t \in [0,T]} $ is a true martingale?

From what I know we should have
$$
E \left[ \int_0^T \mid H_s G_s \mid^2 \; ds \right] < \infty.
$$

This in turn would be guaranteed if
$$
E \left[  \int_0^T |H_s|^4 + |G_s|^4 \; ds \right] < \infty.
$$

Is it possible to have a weaker condition to get a martingale?

Edit: Is it enough to ask for
$$
\int_0^T | H_s G_s |^2 \; ds < \infty, \quad P-a.s. ?
$$

Edit: I was missing some information. $G$ is $dt\otimes P$ square integrable and $E[ \sup_{t \in [0,T] } |H_s|^2 ] < \infty. $ Then
$$
E\left[ \left(\int_0^T | H_s G_s |^2 \; ds \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right] < \infty.   
$$

Thus, $ \int_0^\cdot H_s G_s ds  $ is a true martingale by BDG-inequality.

Comment: Do you have a particular application in mind or are you just asking out of curiousity?

Comment: Im reading a paper. They claim that this particular stochastic integral is a martingale.

Comment: I see; I would say it's not enough to get a (true) martingale... it's only going to be a local martingale.

Comment: Thank you, I missed out on some information, see the edit. I think it works now. Have a nice day.